# EventList<T> a generic list implementation that raises events when items are added and removed

Tags: c#, generics

I created this class for a project when I wanted to have `List<T>` properties on a class and also listen for items being added and removed.

I looked at using [`BindingList<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132679(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`ObservableCollection<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) but I felt that their collection changed events are too complicated. I simply wanted to know when items are added and removed.

```
public class EventList<T> : IList<T>
{
    private readonly List<T> _list;

    public EventList()
    {
        _list = new List<T>();
    }

    public EventList(IEnumerable<T> collection)
    {
        _list = new List<T>(collection);
    }

    public EventList(int capacity)
    {
        _list = new List<T>(capacity);
    }

    public event EventHandler<EventListArgs<T>> ItemAdded;
    public event EventHandler<EventListArgs<T>> ItemRemoved;

    private void RaiseEvent(EventHandler<EventListArgs<T>> eventHandler, T item, int index)
    {
        var eh = eventHandler;
        eh?.Invoke(this, new EventListArgs<T>(item, index));
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _list.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(T item)
    {
        var index = _list.Count;
        _list.Add(item);
        RaiseEvent(ItemAdded, item, index);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        for (var index = 0; index < _list.Count; index++)
        {
            var item = _list[index];
            RaiseEvent(ItemRemoved, item, index);
        }

        _list.Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(T item)
    {
        return _list.Contains(item);
    }

    public void CopyTo(T[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        _list.CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    public bool Remove(T item)
    {
        var index = _list.IndexOf(item);

        if (_list.Remove(item))
        {
            RaiseEvent(ItemRemoved, item, index);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public int Count => _list.Count;
    public bool IsReadOnly => false;

    public int IndexOf(T item)
    {
        return _list.IndexOf(item);
    }

    public void Insert(int index, T item)
    {
        _list.Insert(index, item);
        RaiseEvent(ItemRemoved, item, index);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        var item = _list[index];
        _list.RemoveAt(index);
        RaiseEvent(ItemRemoved, item, index);
    }

    public T this[int index]
    {
        get { return _list[index]; }
        set { _list[index] = value; }
    }
}

public class EventListArgs<T> : EventArgs
{
    public EventListArgs(T item, int index)
    {
        Item = item;
        Index = index;
    }

    public T Item { get; }
    public int Index { get; }
}
```

The typical use case would be something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        MyItems = new EventList<string>();

        MyItems.ItemAdded += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // do something when items are added
        };

        MyItems.ItemRemoved += (sender, args) =>
        {
            // do something when items are removed
        };
    }

    public EventList<string> MyItems { get; } 
}
```

I'm posting this here for code review for general feedback, but also to ask if I've missed something obvious, like an alternative class in the .NET framework or a 3rd party library that might do the same sort of thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Bug**

> ```
> public void Insert(int index, T item)
> {
>     _list.Insert(index, item);
>     RaiseEvent(ItemRemoved, item, index);
> }
> ```

I don't think that you want to raise an `ItemRemoved` event in the case of inserting an item.

---

In general I like your implementation. It is leightweight and is doing exactly what it should.

But for sure I have something to critizise:

- The name `EventList<T>` which reads like a list **of** events instead of a list **with** events. Because there is already a `ObservableCollection<T>` maybe an `ObservableList<T>` would be a better name.
- You implement `IList<T>` but have the underlaying list as a `List<T>` instead of an `IList<T>` like `private readonly IList<T> _list;`.
- <s>The `RemoveAt()` could be simplified by calling the `Remove()` method like so</s>

  ```
  public void RemoveAt(int index)
  {
      Remove(_list[index]);
  }
  ```

  See [@RomanReiner](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/46715/roman-reiner)'s answer [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/111578/29371)
- IMO the raising of multiple `ItemRemoved` events inside the `Clear()` method isn't that good because you are raising the event before the item is removed. You should either have an additional event `ItemsCleared` or you should raise the `ItemRemoved` events after the clearing of that list.

Comment: Great feedback and nicely spotted on the bug. Thanks mate. One question though. What's the advantage of changing the private member to an `IList<T>` vs `List<T>`?

Comment: I agree with most of your points, but what's the reason you don't like the backing implementation for an `IList<T>` being `List<T>`?

Comment: Because you should always code against interfaces rather then implementations. If you implement `IList<T>` it makes sense to restrict the underlaying list to the same interface. You don't use/need any of the `List<T>` methods.

Comment: "The `RemoveAt()` could be simplified by calling the `Remove()` method" Don't do that! The `Remove()` method needs to locate the item before removing it which is a O(n) operation. `RemoveAt()` already has the index so it should be a O(1) operation. Instead, call `RemoveAt()` from `Remove()`.

Comment: I think I'm okay with the way Clear is already implemented. The whole point of the class is that I don't have to listen to different kinds of events (I don't care *how* the items are added / removed, just that they are). Also, to put the Clear before the loop I'd have to make a copy of the list.

Answer (score 5):

Your implementation of the `Remove()` traverses the list twice. First when you do

```
    var index = _list.IndexOf(item);
```

and then again when you call

```
    if (_list.Remove(item))
```

Both are O(n) operations.

Instead, once you obtained the index using the first statement call `RemoveAt(index)`. This also allows you to remove the duplicate event raising code:

```
public bool Remove(T item)
{
    var index = _list.IndexOf(item);

    if (index < 0)
        return false;

    RemoveAt(index);
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I implemented this one exactly as described after reading your previous comment. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
private void RaiseEvent(EventHandler<EventListArgs<T>> eventHandler, T item, int index)
{
    var eh = eventHandler;
    eh?.Invoke(this, new EventListArgs<T>(item, index));
}
```

The conditial invocation will be compiled to something like

```
if (eh != null)
{
    eh.Invoke(this, new EventListArgs<T>(item, index));
}
```

So there is no reason/advantage in having another copy of the `eventHandler` variable in this case. The only reason for using a local copy of the event handler is to avoid the original event handler being set to `null` before the invocation, but the method's parameter won't change. Just use

```
private void RaiseEvent(EventHandler<EventListArgs<T>> eventHandler, T item, int index)
{
    eventHandler?.Invoke(this, new EventListArgs<T>(item, index));
}
```

Comment: Is there a sensible reason you'd ever want to do what the OP did there? I'm no expert and genuinely curious.